Randomness in Keras/Tensorflow RandomFlip (data augmentation)
In Keras/Tensorflow, the RandomFlip layer used in data augmentation, it us supposed that the operation is applied randomly to each image as it passes through the layer during training.
https://devdocs.io/tensorflow~2.3/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/randomflip
I want to know about the randomness of the operation, theres is a seed parameter for reproducibility, but I can't find any other information in the documentation. Asking ChatGPT, I got the following answer:
How RandomFlip Works:

Randomness: 
The RandomFlip layer applies the specified flipping operation (horizontal, vertical, or both) randomly to each image in the batch it processes.

Probability: 
By default, the probability that each image will be flipped is 0.5, or 50%. 
This means that on average, half of the images in any given batch during training will be flipped according to the specified mode.

I'm asking here:
Is there any official documentation that confirms this information?
How can I change the probability factor?
Here is a similar question:
How to set possbility to tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip?
But I would like to know wether the default probability is 50% or not.
If it is really a 50%, then the proposed solution to the given question seems to apply the randomness twice (p, for the paramter + 50% as the default value), so the final factor is p*50%.
Thanks

Does this answer your question? How to set possbility to tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip?

It partially answers, my question. I see that I should implement my own layer, but I would like to see some official documentation, and check wether the default probability is 50% or not.

Keras and TensorFlow are open source, always your best documentation is consulting the source code. See https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/image_augmentation/random_flip/ and click in [source].

GPT is right, there is a 50% chance to flip.
